# Overwrite from branch

Tags: perforce, p4v

I have two branches _trunk and _dev.
There is a folder (actually it's config) where intensive work is performed in both branches.
Now I need to merge from _trunk to _dev. But I need to merge only the code.
The config should be REPLACED. I'm not sure that replacing it manually is right way. How this operation is called? How do you do similair things?

Answer (score 2):

It's an integration as usual, but during resolve you'll accept the source files without trying to merge them into the destination. This will replace the destination files' content with the source content.

Edit: If there are adds and deletes in the source, make sure you let Perforce propagate those with the appropriate options checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an "Integrate/Merge" from _trunk to _dev. Any conflicts will set up in your pending changelist as a "Resolve" for each file.

For code you can let P4V attempt to merge it for you and make changes / do the merge manually. For the config files, in the resolve window do "Accept Source" - this overrides the target with the source regardless.

Likewise, if there's any where you know you don't want to bring your changes forward but still want it to recognise  you've checked and accomodated for the changes, use "Accept Target"